# RestKit: connecting many-to-many relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I've got the following Core Data model is my app:

```
+--------------------+         +-------------+
| Ingredient         |         | Dish        |
+--------------------+         +-------------+
| id                 |         | id          |
| title              |         | title       |
| dishId (transient) |
+--------------------+         +-------------+
| dishes             | <<--->> | ingredients |
+--------------------+         +-------------+
```

I also have a webservice, which allows me to request all ingredients for a given dish like this:

```
/dish/1/ingredients
```

(where `1` is some dish id).

The request to such response is as follows:

```
{
    { "id": "1", "title": "milk" },
    { "id": "2", "title": "egg" },
    { "id": "3", "title": "flour" }
}
```

I've read about RKConnectionDescription, but I can't figure out how to use it to connect these two entities in this particular case.

Here's the mapping I've got so far:

```
RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Ingredient" inManagedObjectStore:store];

[mapping setIdentificationAttributes:@[@"id"]];

[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
        @"id" : @"id",
        @"title" : @"title",
        @"@metadata.dishId" : @"dishId"
}];
```

**UPDATE**

I've added a new transient property `dishId` to my `Ingredient` entity and tried to set up connection like this:

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription =
        [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Ingredient" inManagedObjectContext:mainContext];
NSRelationshipDescription *relationship =
        [entityDescription relationshipsByName][@"dishes"];
RKConnectionDescription *connection =
        [[RKConnectionDescription alloc] initWithRelationship:relationship attributes:@{
                @"dishId" : @"id"
        }];

[mapping addConnection:connection];
```

but each time I request ingredients for another dish, it replaces old connections with a new ones, so I basically get one-to-one relationship. For example, I first request ingredients for omelette, and it connects omelette to eggs, milk and flour. Then I request ingredients for pancakes, and it connects pancakes to eggs, milk and flour, however omelette connection to these ingredients is lost.

`assignmentPolicy` is not available on `RKConnectionDescription`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [`RKRoute`](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKRoute.html) to create the request path and to provide you with the required relationship mapping (you don't need to do it yourself). You need to set the path pattern for the route to `/dish/:id/ingredients` so that the identity is pulled from the `Dish` and injected.

Use `routeWithRelationshipName:objectClass:pathPattern:method:` to create the route.

Use `getObjectsAtPathForRelationship:ofObject:parameters:success:failure:` to get the contents.

Once you have the route connected, any mapping that it does will be provided with the URL content metadata. So, in your mapping you use:

```
@"@metadata.routing.parameters.id" : @"dishId"
```

Note that `dishId` is a new transient attribute added to `Ingredient` that you use in your foreign key mapping (`RKConnectionDescription`).

Comment: I have no problem getting dish id from metadata. I just don't know how to setup `RKConnectionDescription` for many-to-many relationship when I only have single dishId per request.

Comment: Usually you want to merge the new data with the existing data (rather than replace it). Set the relationship mapping to use `RKUnionAssignmentPolicy` does that, but I can't say I've ever needed to do it with a foreign mapping so I'll need to check later. I'm guessing you see the connection made but other (existing) connections broken?

Comment: yes, exactly. Please look at the update of the question.

Comment: Checking the code for `RKRelationshipConnectionOperation`, there doesn't appear to be a way to do it. The relationship is always set and no option to merge. I haven't scanned github for branches that change that. You may need to implement it yourself...

Comment: OK, thanks for you answers, seems like it's just easier to establish this connection manually in completion block.