# Connecting a relationship with RestKit without foreign keys

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, restkit

I'm trying to connect a many-to-many relationship with RestKit.

Suppose we have 2 entities:

User, returned by `/user/:login_name`:

```
{
    id: 1234,
    name: 'Joe Bloggs',
    ...
}
```

and Group, returned by `/user/:login_name/groups`:

```
[
    {
        id: 2345,
        name: 'Diggers',
        ...
    },
    {   id: 2346,
        name: 'Fillers',
        ...
    },
    ...
]
```

Each user can belong to several groups and each group can have several users.

My Core Data models reflect the data returned by API plus have `User.groups` and `Group.users` relationships.

The problem is no foreign keys are returned by API: there's neither `User.groups` nor `Group.users` collection. So, as far as I understand, I can not use `RKConnectionDescription` in this case?

It looks like `[RKRoute routeWithRelationshipName:objectClass:pathPattern:method:]` could have been used, but I'm not using object mapping and it looks like routing can't be used with entity mapping.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RKConnectionDescription`, but you will need to tread carefully...

You should use a route. The important part is for RestKit to collect `:login_name` in the routing metadata and then you can use that in your mapping.

It means you need to request the user before you request the group so that there is something in the DB to find.

You also need to set RestKit to use `RKAssignmentPolicyUnion` so that your relationships are built up rather than being replaced.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22796868/restkit-connecting-many-to-many-relationship) for more details on route and metadata. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374504/core-data-relationship-lost-after-fetching-more-objects-into-the-entities) for `RKAssignmentPolicyUnion` details.